# Move videos from photo seems downsizing it or compressing

Tags: macos, photos.app

When I watch video using Photos [image] it looks good. But when I simple move video file from Photos to Desktop and watch it then it looks like it was downsized or kind of. How to export/move to desktop video as is?

Comment: Are you speaking about playing the videos in QuickTime Player or playing using the Quickview function in the Finder (select + press Space bar)? Quickview may be playing HD videos in reduced size.

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous ok let me check, so do you think is that not issue, but player optimization. Let me check in QuickTime player.

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous I played in in Photos and using Quick Time and quality much better in Photos I guess much more!

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous ok I found it, but thanks for help! Answered on my question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found an option File>Export>Original

[image]